# Why is there a light outlining this picture when I push the info icon?

Tags: camera-basics

[image]My boyfriend sent me this picture of him at work when I go to push the info icon for the picture to see what time it was taken this glowing outlined light appears?

Answer (score 3):

It's the subject separation outline an iPhone generates.

If you long press the [usually human] subject of a photo, you'll see a white graphic glow spread across the subject, then the outside edge will glow in a cycle around the subject.
You can then lift out the subject to a new image or save to a new file, copy/paste it or share it, or just tap again to remove the outline.